# How to filter rows in a DataFrame in Pandas uisng for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, filter

I have a csv file which has a large number of columns (20+). I want to filter the time column ("mins") so that it creates 60 separate dataframes which contains all the data for each minute. I can achieve it using this method below, but it is possible to do it using a for loop instead of repeating myself 60 times?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

mins_0 = df[df['mins']==0]
mins_1 = df[df['mins']==1]
mins_2 = df[df['mins']==2]
mins_3 = df[df['mins']==3]
....
mins_59 = df[df['mins']==59]
```

Comment: I don't think you really want to do that.  Maybe reconsider what your goals are and why you would want to have separate dataframes.

Comment: `mins = [x for _, x in df.groupby('mins')]`

Comment: or `{f"mins_{grp}" : data for grp, data in df.groupby('mins')}`

Answer (score 0):

I still likes the `pd.group_by` in the comments better, but it is also doable by using `np.unique()` to find all unique values in the table and choose them in buckets.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

df_list = [df[df['mins']==x] for x in in.unique(df['mins'].values)]
```

Answer (score -1):

As per Chris's comment, you may want to reconsider why you are doing this, but if you wanted to, this is a way you might go about it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

each_min = []

for i in range(60):
    each_min.append(df[df['mins'] == i])
```

this will put each dataframe in a list for you, you could also modify it to put them in a dictionary with each minute being the keys of the dictionary